# COMODO Antivirus - dependent of libssl0.9.8 and multiarch-support?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, antivirus

I can't install COMODO Antivirus on my laptop. I use Ubuntu 20.04 and this is really weird, but when I run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i cav-linux_x64.deb
```

it shows this message:

```
Depends on libssl0.9.8:amd64
```

I tried to install it, using:

sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8:amd64

(because my system is amd64) and it returns:

```
dpkg: erro ao processar o arquivo /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 não foi possível abrir '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.0.9.8.dpkg-new': Ficheiro ou pasta inexistente
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                         Foram encontrados erros enquanto processava:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know what to do. I tried installing `multiarch-support` too, because when I tried to install just `libssl0.9.8`, it said that `multiarch-support` was a dependency. Can you help me?

P.S.: Sorry for the Portuguese in the command line, I think that just copying could help to solve the problem better than translating:

```
(A ler a base de dados ... 262033 ficheiros e directórios actualmente instalados.)
A preparar para desempacotar cav-linux_x64.deb ...
A descompactar cav-linux (1.1.268025-1) sobre (1.1.268025-1) ...

Uninstallation succeed!

dpkg: problemas com dependências impedem a configuração de cav-linux:
 cav-linux depende de libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8m-1); no entanto:
  O pacote libssl0.9.8:amd64 não está instalado.

dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote cav-linux (--install):
 problemas com dependências - a deixar por configurar
Foram encontrados erros enquanto processava:
 cav-linux
```

Comment: I don't think Comodo AV has worked on Ubuntu for years. Install `clamav` and `clamtk` instead.

Comment: Or none at all. Unless you have a very specific user case, an AV in Linux is seldom needed.

Comment: @heynnema I hated clamav, it hasn't got functions that I usually use.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I only want COMODO because I always used it and I taught it would be good to have an extra protection

Comment: When you tried clamav, did you also install clamtk? Comodo won't work anymore... as I said in my first comment.

Comment: @heynnema Yes, I installed clamav, clamtk and a bunch of other recommended packages, but I simply don't like the interface/functions.

Comment: You may have to use the CLI to scan the folders you desire. See `man clamscan`.